# Please check my problem solved. The task was to calculate $M^{100}$, where M is a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, problem-solving

Again, o points for this problem. 
And there's a small mis-type in the beginning where t1=t2=t3=t=1, it's actually -1

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer seems correct. You can check [here](http://matrixcalc.org/en/)

Comment: Who is the sadistic teacher that asks to perform such computations *by hand*?

Comment: Thanks. I know it's correct.

Comment: The teacher is not sadistic, it's a math contest and the calculations aren't very complex.

Comment: Since $100_{10} = 1100100_2$, it might be quicker to perform $8$ matrix multiplications: $6$ to compute $M^{2^i}$ and $2$ to compute $M^{100} = M^{2^6} M^{2^5} M^{2^2}$. I didn't try this, though.